# When to use Self?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, self

I am new to iOS development.

I have property as follows,

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *dataArray;
```

I am doing the following, to alloc it

```
self.dataArray=[[NSMutable alloc]init];
```

In the dealloc I am doing the following

```
-(void)delloc{
  [dataArray release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

But I am getting memory leak for my array initialization.However , it doesn't create the

leak when I don't use self. But I wonder is it a write approach to initialise the array

without using self. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have a need to support iOS 3, I recommend you switch to ARC - it will (mostly) save you the pain of memory management. As for your question, when initialising you are accessing the property, but when releasing you are accessing the associated iVar. Try to keep to one convention or the other.

Comment: when you are using `MRC`, this one would be more correct in the `-dealloc` method: `[self.dataArray release];` or `[_dataArray release];`

Comment: please note, there is no such an object `NSMutable` (until you don't create one), so in your case I think the proper code is `self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: the title doesnt match the content and I would urge to use ARC too BUT ANYWAYS I'd recommend you read a 'beggining objC book' (_NO offense inteded_ but this is the general basics and not a concrete question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a leak because the dataArray property is declared with retain, which means that when you use self (thus you use the setter), your retain count goes up to 2 and you only release it once. On the other hand, if you only use the ivar, the retain count is 1 (because of alloc) and you release it once, which is fine. To avoid the memory leak in the first situation, autorelease it like this.

self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

That will balance the retain count. As for access, except for inside the dealloc method, try to use self (setter and getter)

You should read the memory management docs, first thing to start with when developing for Cocoa Touch.

Also, why don't you use ARC?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `self.` signature you are accessing to the object via automatically generated / custom getter/setter. The setter will tipically manage the memory and you don't need to do that.
If you don't use self you access directly to the object.

The code what you presented is leaking, because the default setter of the `dataArray` will retain to the array, what you set with `self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
The correct usage is:

```
self.dataArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or:

```
_dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that `alloc` is adding one to the retain count of the new object.  The property reference is also retaining the object.  If you want to do it this way, you only want one of those.  A common method is:

```
self.dataArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] autorelease];
```

However, better still is to use ARC as @c.cam108 suggested and avoid the whole problem.